# Attempting to connect classes, where one class has a list the other class

Tags: python, python-3.x, class

I'm trying to have two classes where one class has a list of the other class. Like a Bag class that has a list of what Balls are in it, where Ball is a class.

```
class Bag:
    Inside = []

    def CreateBag(self):
        self.Inside.append(Ball("Blue", "Small"))

class Ball:
    def __init__(self, Color, Size):
        self.Color = Color
        self.Size = Size

B = Bag()
B.CreateBag()
print(B.Inside)
```

When I do `print(B.Inside)` I get `[<__main__.Ball object at 0x000002B7EFF8BA20>]`. I've tried `B.Inside.Color`, but that gives me an error, making me think I have set this up wrong.

Comment: What exactly is your question? You've done everything right except accessing the `Color` of the `Ball` instance inside `B`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the basics, although try to follow [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) (Style Guide for Python Code).  To display objects beyond the default "<object @ address>" you have to define a [`__repr__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__repr__) (debug representation) of the object, and perhaps a [`__str__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__str__) (print representation):

```py
class Bag:

    def __init__(self):
        self.inside = []

    def add(self, item):
        self.inside.append(item)

    def __repr__(self):
        return f'Bag({self.inside})'

    def __getitem__(self,index):
        return self.inside[index]

    def __setitem__(self,index,value):
        self.inside[index] = value

class Ball:

    def __init__(self, color, size):
        self.color = color
        self.size = size

    def __repr__(self):
        return f'Ball(color={self.color!r}, size={self.size!r})'

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.size} {self.color} Ball'

bag = Bag()
bag.add(Ball('Blue','Small'))
bag.add(Ball('Red','Big'))
print(bag)                      # uses Bag.__repr__ since Bag.__str__ isn't defined
print(bag[0])                   # uses Bag.__getitem__ and Ball.__str__
bag[0] = Ball('Green','Medium') # uses Bag.__setitem__
print(bag)
print(bag[0].color)
```

```
Bag([Ball(color='Blue', size='Small'), Ball(color='Red', size='Big')])
Small Blue Ball
Bag([Ball(color='Green', size='Medium'), Ball(color='Red', size='Big')])
Green
```